# Visual Studio 2022: Bold font in the entire editor

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2022

I downloaded & installed Visual Studio 2022. After creating a new project, and playing with the IDE for some time, I noticed that my font size was set to bold everywhere in the editor. Keywords, operators, punctuation, strings, variables, functions, classes, everything! Obviously I tried to change the size of the font, but it always reverts back to being bold.

Did I do something to cause this? How can I change it to not use bold font everywhere?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is due to Microsoft changing the default font in Visual Studio 2022 from Consolas to Cascadia Code: a font which is designed to make text easier to read for people with disabilities like Character Dysmorphia or Dyslexia. You can change this back to "Consolas", the VS 2019 font by going to

Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > "Show settings for: Text Edit" > Font: "Consolas"

Comment: Yes, this was it for me... It wasn't really bold, just looks unusual, getting back to the font I am used to helped me a lot.

Comment: Awesome! The new font looks soo fuzzy and unclean :)

Comment: The new font seems to have **different widths for spaces when bolded!** So due to syntax highlighting braces don't line up visually with code even when the indentation is correct. This was driving me crazy. Totally inappropriate for a fixed-width coding font. >:( Thank you for the solution.

Comment: FYI, Dysmorphia is the obsession that someone has over their body being disfigured, or not perfectly semetric. You cannot design a font to help with that

Comment: Funny thing is my dyslexia meant I didn't notice the different font name when compared settings in VS 2019 and VS 2022.

Answer (score 6):

---

#### SO THERE ARE A COUPLE OF ISSUES THAT CAUSE THE FONT TO RENDER OVERLY BOLD

---

I know that this answer isn't as popular as the other answer, but there was more to this problem than just changing the font. Originally, I tried changing the font, and it didn't work. It turned out, I had somehow turned on an option called "Windows High Contrast" which renders the font as an "ANSI Standardized Terminal Emulators" where there is an option of font that is not only more saturated & brighter, but bolder as well. Only then did changing the font back to the Original Microsoft Consoles font provide the experience I had expected.

##### Even Here the Story Doesn't End

I later found out about a feature called Power-lines, which is a really awesome looking feature, and provides a great command-line experience. And `Cascadia Code` supports Power-lines, Consoles does not.

Also I have to read code in a foreign language occasionally, and [Slavic/Asian Languages render very nicely in Cascadia Code](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code#font-features). So after over 6 months of grappling with fonts. I found that Cascadia Code actually has a variable font-weight, such that 300 and 400 are valid weights, but so 350, or 565 (too bold).

So for me, what worked, was to change Cascadia Codes weight to 350. Its actually kind of cool to be able to pick a font's boldness using a dynamic weight, rather than being restricted to increments of 100.

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Environment
4. Fonts and Colors
5. Text Edit
6. Font Weight: `350`

###### Image Showing Windows Terminal w/ Power Lines Support

[image]

Comment: I don't think it was you who caused that setting to be on. It was enabled for me as well, on a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Oh, really? I feel like it should be a setting that goes in a set of accessibility options, not something in the general environment menu. I posted this to hopefully save some people the headache that it caused me. It me almost 4 hours of filtering through crap to find out how to get it off.

Comment: This was also on for me... but turning it off still has everything bold, even after restarting and checking it is off. Did this unbold things for you?

Comment: @AndyJones the bold comes from the new font in 22. you can change back to Consolas (you put "font" into the search bar of the options menu to find the tab)

Comment: 1. Tools, 2. options, 3. environment, 4. Fonts & Colors. From there you can change the font, the font colors, font weights, etc...

Comment: After changing the font, it still looked blurry for me. I noticed that scroll wheel zooming didn't hit 100%, and this caused bad antialiasing, making it still look bold, and a little blurry. I manually selected 100% from the bottom left of the text editor, and now it's clean Consolas typeface.